# Debugging a ppc64 custom OS using QEMU

Tags: qemu, powerpc, osdev

I am trying to write a simple powerpc64 OS using openfirmware and qemu. My main difficulties come from the lack of a good debug output to use when printing useful information.

When developing for the x86 platform I would use the `0xE9` CPU IO port for printing, and I would redirect it to the stdout of my console using `-debugcon stdio`, but when searching in the online documentation of QEMU and in several forums I could not find an equivalent for ppc64.

Is there any mechanism like the `0xE9` QEMU-specific CPU port in the x86 platform that can be used for debugging when coding for ppc64, in the same fashion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenFirmware and haven't quiesced it yet, perhaps you could get somewhere with the `write` OpenFirmware call.

See e.g. Linux's [`prom_printf()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/powerpc/kernel/prom_init.c#L468) in `arch/powerpc/kernel/prom_init.c`.